# Why are my values not updating in the Home page? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So i was making a weather app , but it does not update itself when i search for a city it just works for the first time and after that if I search any city name the values won't update at all.

Here is the main Homepage code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:glass_kit/glass_kit.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';


import '../model/model.dart';
import '../services/remote_services.dart';
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Post? posts;
  var isLoaded=true;
  var pressure ;
  var city = new TextEditingController();
  @override

  getData(String city) async{
    posts=await RemoteService().getPosts(city);
    if(posts!=null){
      setState((){
        isLoaded= true;
        print("Weather");
        print(posts?.wind.speed);
        print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);
        print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
        pressure= posts?.main.pressure;

      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var timezone;
    return Scaffold(

      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/Clouds.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Visibility(
              visible: isLoaded,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        GlassContainer.clearGlass(
                          borderWidth: 0,
                          height: 50,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-70,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: city,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white
                            ),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Enter City",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                        GlassContainer.clearGlass(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 50,
                          borderWidth: 0,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          child: Center(
                            child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: (){
                                getData(city.text);
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.white,),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5,),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            GlassContainer.clearGlass(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/8.099,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3.990,
                              borderWidth: 0,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              blur: 10,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.water, color: Colors.white,),
                                  Text(
                                    posts==null?" ":"${posts?.main.humidity}%",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 24
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5,),
                            GlassContainer.clearGlass(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/8.099,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3.990,
                              borderWidth: 0,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              blur: 10,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.wind, color: Colors.white,),
                                  Text(
                                    posts==null?" ":"${posts?.wind.speed}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 24
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "Km/h",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      color: Colors.white
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                        GlassContainer.clearGlass(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.51102941,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3.77731092-10,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderWidth: 0,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  posts==null?" ":"${posts?.main.temp} C",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 75,
                                    color: Colors.white,

                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                Text(
                                  posts==null?"":"Feels like ${posts?.main.feelsLike} C",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    color: Colors.white
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),

                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 7,),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        GlassContainer.clearGlass(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.51102941,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3.77731092-10+12,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderWidth: 0,
                          child: new CircularPercentIndicator(
                            radius: 90.0,
                            lineWidth: 13.0,
                            animation: true,
                            percent: pressure==null?0:pressure/1084,
                            center:  Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                FaIcon((pressure!=null)?(pressure>1013)?FontAwesomeIcons.arrowUp:FontAwesomeIcons.arrowDown:FontAwesomeIcons.arrowDown, color: Colors.white,),
                                Text(
                                  "$pressure mB",
                                  style:
                                  new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                            progressColor: Colors.white,
                          ),

                        ),
                        Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            GlassContainer.clearGlass(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/8.099,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3.990,
                              borderWidth: 0,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              blur: 10,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.temperatureArrowUp, color: Colors.white,),
                                  Text(
                                    "${posts?.main.tempMax} C",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 24
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 18,),
                            GlassContainer.clearGlass(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/8.099,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3.990,
                              borderWidth: 0,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              blur: 10,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.temperatureArrowDown, color: Colors.white,),
                                  Text(
                                    "${posts?.main.tempMin} C",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 24
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Expanded(child: SizedBox())

                      ],
                    ),
                    // GlassContainer.clearGlass(height: height, width: width)

                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

setState is not working as it should i would be glad if some fixed this as soon as possible

Here is the code for the RemoteService class, it requests from the Uri.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../model/model.dart';

class RemoteService{
  Future <Post?> getPosts(String city) async{
    var client =  http.Client();
    var uri = Uri.parse("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$city&appid=5e749d88f2df02cacc9be6abf8088531&units=metric");
    var response = await client.get(uri);
    if (response.statusCode==200){
      var json=response.body;

      return postFromJson(json);

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Try to make async call when press iconButton IconButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                await getData(city.text);
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.white,),
                            )

Answer (score 0):

Once the data is loaded `posts` is no more null which doesnt satisfy the condition mentioned in the get data method. Please remove the condition `if posts!= null` in getdata. Also please remove override mentioned above getdata if you have added it by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating all parameters in setstate() just like pressure. This will work.